# Replace JQuery for contenteditable element event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contenteditable

I'm using JQuery in my project, and the only line it gets used is the following:

```
$('#div').on('input', function() { ... });
```

Is there a more lightweight lib/polyfill I can use instead, which allows to register an input event on a contenteditable div?

Comment: No. This is it.

Comment: Use javascript instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **pure javascript** you can do something likes that :

```
document
   .getElementsByTagName("div")
   .addEventListener('input', function() { ... }));
```

And add this **html attribute** `contenteditable="true"` on your div.